# Pressing 'tab' in testcafe with .pressKey('tab') then using .typeTest()

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am writing a test for website,and I wish to type something click tab then keep typeing I have the following test:

```
   await t.typeText(Selector('[title|="City"]'),'St. Petersburg')
   await t.typeText(Selector('[title|="Street Address"]'),'777 The Heavenly Vulga')
   await t.typeText(Selector('[title|="Telephone"]'),'6085550119')
   await t.typeText(Selector('.input-text.validate-zip-international.required-entry'),'40475')
   await t.pressKey('tab')
   await t.typeText(???,email)
```

My question is how can I type into the box i just 'tabbed' into.  Since typeText requires a selector as the first argument.  Note: I DO want to use the tab here.  What do I put for the ???, and is there a way for t.pressKey('tab') to return a selector because it is returning a object now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) as a Selector:

```
.typeText(() =>  document.activeElement, 'Hello world')
```

or use [pressKey](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/presskey.html) action in the following way:

```
.pressKey('H e l l o space w o r l d')
```